Cypress PSoC5 UART Half Duplex mode - Trouble transmitting data after UART_LoadTxConfig()
I'm currently trying to transmit data using the built-in UART component of the CY8C5888LTI-LP097. UART is configured in Half-Duplex mode at 9600 Bd, 8 Data bits and even parity. My code looks like this:

uint8 transmitData(char* message, char len)
{
    //CyGlobalIntDisable;
    UART_1_LoadTxConfig();
    for(int i= 0; i<len;i++)
    {
        UART_1_PutChar(message[i]);
    }
    while((UART_1_ReadTxStatus()& UART_1_TX_STS_COMPLETE)!=UART_1_TX_STS_COMPLETE);
    UART_1_LoadRxConfig();
    //CYGlobalIntEnable;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    CyGlobalIntEnable; /* Enable global interrupts. */    
    
    UART_1_Start();
    UART_1_LoadTxConfig(); 
    char message[] = {0x12, 0x13,0x14, 0x02, 0x00, 0x39,0x07,0xFF,0xFA,0x50};
    for(;;)
    {       
        transmitData(message,10);
        CyDelay(50);
    }
}


My problem is, using this code results in only 4 message Bytes being transmitted. The resulting output is: {0x50,0x13,0x14,0x02} and then the 50ms delay (according to the Logic analyzer hooked up to the output Pin)
Using only the TX mode, the transmission works just as intendet. What i noticed though, the very first transmission after the start of the PSoC looks just like the Output described above, this can be solved by moving the 50ms delay before the transmitData(). So I assume my problem has something to do with the UART_LoadTx() needing quite some time to set up the TX mode properly.
On the other hand the documentation for the UART_LoadTx() function specifically states:
Description: Loads the transmitter configuration in half duplex mode. After calling this function, the UART 
             is ready to transmit data. 

It also states I must make sure that the previous transaction is completed, which I think I did (because the PutChar() function should be blocking and I wait for the completion of the last byte). In case I didn't, I'd be happy to know what mistake I did.
Thanks for your help.

Why does your code refer to both UART_1 and UART_2?

I'm using two UART components, UART_1 is for the serial interface with my PC. I wanted to edit the code before posting this such that there is only UART_1 but apparently I forgot to do so in the other instances. Thanks for pointing this out, I just edited the post accordingly
